# Making a pause before the program ends

Tags: c, user-input

I have a question about a thingy I need to do in my code,

I need to pause the code before it ends, for example there's a switch case
for

1-etc
2-etc
3
.
.
5-etc

when i click 9 for instance,the output is

```
printf("This option is unknown.\nThe program exits.\n");
```

now what I need to do :  Is after this massage the program needs to stop and when I press "enter"  it will continue to "press any key to continue",

would very much appreciate the help.

EDIT: `     default:

```
        printf("This option is unknown.\nThe program exits.\n");
        getchar();
        system("pause");
        break;`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Read about `getchar()`.

Comment: does the "getchar" I inserted in the main post is correct? because it doesn't work for me

Comment: @alexdr3x It seems you need one more `getchar()`, as the one currently is considering the last ENTER keypress input.

Comment: @Natasha Dutta, thank you so much it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the actual code, so it's tough saying what's actually going on there, but I'll assume your function calls an `exit()`.

You need to add some code which waits for user input, before the control reaches the `exit()`. An example, [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar), will just do the job for you.

Before you call for the `exit()` (or a `return`), you need to add

```
while ('\n' != getchar());           //rough way to clean input buffer
puts("press any key to continue");   //print message
getchar();                           //wait for any new key press
```

Comment: I added the part I need at the post because the original code is very long, did you mean it like that?

Comment: @alexdr3x You dont need the `system("pause");` part., I believe.

Comment: well I removed the system pause, and it goes right in to "press any key to continue"... even with the getchar()

Answer (score 0):

Try system("PAUSE"). Library needed: stdlib.h

Comment: I actually did that but it just holds the program from shutting down, I need it to wait for an "enter" key

Comment: Try to use a while loop, telling the program to check the input and, when the enter button in pressed, to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am very curious about your final code which resolved this issue.
I wrote a sample code that kind of mimic your situation.
Please take a look at the following code and let me know if this is what you did to fix this problem.  Thanks

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int
 main(void)
 {
     char ch;

     printf("Please enter an option [1,2,3,4,5 (return to exit):");
     while( ( ch = getchar() ) !='\n' )
     {

         switch(ch)
         {
            case '1':
               printf("hello 1\n");
               break;
            case '2':
               printf("hello 2\n");
               break;
            case '3':
               printf("hello 3\n");
               break;
             case '4':
                printf("hello 4\n");
                break;
             case '5':
                printf("hello 5\n");
                break;
             default:
                printf("unknown option. Press a key to continue. (return to exit)\n");
                break;
         }
         printf("Please enter an option [1,2,3,4,5 (return to exit):");

         ch = getchar();
   }

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: actually I followed a suggestion by Natasha, and just added two get chars, and it did the effect I wanted.